# Video player with ability to set SW/HW for Audio and Video separately

Tags: applications, audio, video

I want following: be able to set hardware mode for video decoding and software mode for audio. Best players I have seen so far support one switch for both. Am I corrent that hardware mode for video is beneficial in terms performance/battery life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MX Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) does HW video / SW audio.